# SQL Server Agent Job - Script to drop table and replace with .bak file

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I drop a database table with sql server agent jobs, and upload a new .bak file using a scripts in sql

This is a well functioning script for *sql server agent jobs*. How can I do the same to replace the same for tables with .bak file ?

```
DECLARE @jobId binary(16)

SELECT @jobId = job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE (name = N'Name of Your Job')
IF (@jobId IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @jobId
END

DECLARE @ReturnCode int
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'Name of Your Job'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused with the replace with .bak file, but I assume that you mean that the .bak file is containing the CREATE TABLE sql script.

1. To drop the database table:

```
DROP TABLE [schema].[table_name];
```

2. To recreate the database table from a backup script file:

```
-- Declare variable.
DECLARE @BulkColumn nvarchar(max);

-- Read information from the backup script file and store it in the variable.
SELECT @BulkColumn = [BulkColumn] FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'<PATH_TO_FILE>', SINGLE_CLOB) AS Contents;

-- Execute the contents of the script dynamically.
EXECUTE sp_executesql @BulkColumn;
```

You can test this first in SSMS, to avoid any undesired issues, make sure you know what the backup script file looks like before executing it.

Creat a SQL Job and add a step of Type: Transact-SQL script and select the correct Database, paste in the script and give it a try.